# Is it possible align ToolbarTray on right side?

Tags: wpf, material-design-in-xaml

Is it possible with [WPF/ MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML)
to display `ToolBar` as Dock right aligned?
Default is left aligned.

[image]

I think I should modify [this Style file](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/master/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.ToolBar.xaml).

but I could not find "DockPanel.Dock="Left"

```
 <ToolBarTray>
        <ToolBar Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignToolBar}" ClipToBounds="False" >

            <Button ToolTip="Home">
                <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Home" />
            </Button>
            <Button ToolTip="Add">
                <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="AccountMultiplePlus" />
            </Button>
            <Button ToolTip="Test">
                <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="FlagCheckered" />
            </Button>
            <Separator />
            <Button ToolTip="Layer" >
                <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Layers" />
            </Button>
            <Separator />
            <Button ToolTip="Setting" >
                <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Settings" />
            </Button>
            <Button ToolTip="Help">
                <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="HelpCircleOutline" />
            </Button>

        </ToolBar>
    </ToolBarTray>
```

Comment: FlowDirection="RightToLeft"

Comment: It's works ! : ) Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<ToolBarTray FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
    <ToolBar Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignToolBar}" ClipToBounds="False" >

        <Button ToolTip="Home">
            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Home" />
        </Button>
        <Button ToolTip="Add">
            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="AccountMultiplePlus" />
        </Button>
        <Button ToolTip="Test">
            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="FlagCheckered" />
        </Button>
        <Separator />
        <Button ToolTip="Layer" >
            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Layers" />
        </Button>
        <Separator />
        <Button ToolTip="Setting" >
            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Settings" />
        </Button>
        <Button ToolTip="Help">
            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="HelpCircleOutline" />
        </Button>

    </ToolBar>
</ToolBarTray>
```